# Errors on IBM mobilefirst Mobile browser simulator console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I created an application using IBM mobilefirst and my application is working fine, but when I look at my console in mobile first browser I find out some errors.How to resolve these errors?[image]

Comment: Can you provide your exact mfpdev-cli version. Also, do you see this error if you run on a device or emulator?

Comment: I am using mobilefirst 8.0 version

Comment: The exact version please. In your command line execute "mfpdev -version".

Comment: exact version is 8.0.0-2017091111